# R Packages downloaded in private since new R update on macOS

Tags: r, macos, install.packages

Since the new update of R on my Mac (version 11.2.2), I can't download any package.
Well, I can, but it is placed inside a "private" folder, while it's specified that it should be in my Library.

For instance, when I want to download 'mapsf' it gives me this error:

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/elifka/Library/R/3.6/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘mapsf’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) y
installing the source package ‘mapsf’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mapsf_0.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2904481 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

* installing *source* package ‘mapsf’ ...
** package ‘mapsf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c init.c -o init.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c layout.cpp -o layout.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -Wl,-rpath,/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o mapsf.so RcppExports.o init.o layout.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: framework not found CoreFoundation
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mapsf.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mapsf’
* removing ‘/Users/elifka/Library/R/3.6/library/mapsf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mapsf’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/h3/vt0n6y2534b35ss3dzf_037m0000gn/T/RtmpV1gjTe/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried to put `type='binary'`in the `install.packages()` as it was suggested in another post, butit did not do the work.
I also tried to put 'no' for compilation and it did not work neither.

Cheers,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Deleting R Studio and R and reinstalling both worked form me too

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I fixed it by deleting R Studio and R and reinstalling both.